# Setup config for my SSD [Ultrabay T430]

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, ssd, fstab

there are a lot of blog posts about how to configure Ubuntu when using an SSD. The ones I found rely on editing `/etc/fstab`. Unfortunately my file looks different from their samples which is why I'm unsure how to proceed. This is my setup:

T430 Laptop; Ubuntu 12.04 LTS;
Ubuntu is installed on an SSD located in my Ultra-bay slot. There is a Windows installation on my main HDD.

This is the content of fstab:

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Nothing in `/etc/fstab.d/`:

```
ll /etc/fstab.d
drwxr-xr-x 2   root root 1024 Mar 30 2012 ./
drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 9216 Apr 3 10:15 ../
```

According to [Site 1](http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html) or [Site 2](http://janneinosaka.blogspot.ch/2012/08/t430-and-ubuntu.html) I should be able to see a list of all disk there and then add some flags for my SSD but all I see are the two lines above.

Any idea how I should proceed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some fstab settings are placed in `/etc/fstab.d/` folder, you may check?

Comment: @Sneetsher Nothing:  

  `ll /etc/fstab.d`  
  `drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1024 Mar 30  2012 ./`
  `drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 9216 Apr  3 10:15 ../`